# How can I synchronized two process accessing on the same resources?

Tags: linux, synchronized

I have two processes which access to the same physical memory(GPIO data addr). 
So how can I have synchronized between these apps?
I understand that we have some kind of locking mechanism such as mutex and semaphore, so which method is the fastest?

Thank for your help,

-nm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mutexes and semaphores are generally considered to be concurrency solutions in the same address space -- meaning that different parts of the same program will lock their access to a resource using one of these contraptions.

When you're dealing with separate processes, the standard way to do this on Linux is to create something in `/var/lock`, like `/var/lock/myapp.lock`, and [place your PID followed by a newline in it](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/2.2/fhs-5.9.html). Then other processes will check for its existence, and if you're crafty check the PID to make sure it's still alive, too.

If you need real-time access to the area, skip the filesystem and the processes will have to communicate via IPC (`LET_ME_KNOW_WHEN_DONE`, `OKAY_IM_DONE`, you get the idea), or -- better -- write a process whose sole purpose is to read and write to the GPIO memory, and your other programs communicate with **it** via IPC (probably the best approach).

Comment: mutexes and semaphores certainly can be used cross-process.  the lock file approach is going to be slower than either.

Comment: In particular, POSIX mutexes and condition variables on Linux support shared memory, with `pthread_mutexattr_setpshared` and friends. This is probably the lowest-overhead IPC mechanism available on Linux. However it is a good bit more complex to use properly.

Answer (score 0):

mutex means mutual exclusion -- a semaphore is just a variable used to determine if the resource is in use. In windows, there is a Mutex object that can be created to protect a shared resource.

The issue is what language are you using? What OS (I am assuming linux). Most languages provide support for multi-threading and mutual exclusion, and you should use the built-in constructs.

For example, using C on Linux, you might want to

include semaphore.h

and look up the calls for sem_init, sem_wait etc.

Comment: The question is tagged Linux.